# How to Check if PostgreSQL Array Contains Value or Substring of Value

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I want to make a query that displays the data of the table for which column x contains the value '11'. Column x being an array.

I find:

```
x = ['2114', '111', '321', '11']

Select * 
from table_1 WHERE '11' = ANY(x)
```

but this match only for `'11'`, instead I wish this will match for `'2114'` `'111'` and `'11'`

I also have a problem because I need to create this query dynamically.

```
if condition:
    return f" %s = ANY(x)"
else:
    return f"{field_name} like %s"  ## '_' || %s || '_'
```

For else condition, if I write `'%' || %s || '%'`, I receive an error: *IndexError: tuple index out of range*

Comment: can you post the script you've tried ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option is an EXISTS condition:

```
Select t.*
from table_1 t
WHERE exists (select *
              from unnest(t.x) as u(element)
              where u.element like '%11%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ikWQncKZgZA8h6u7hN1T6F/0))

```
Select x,array_to_string(x,';')
from table_1 
WHERE array_to_string(x,';') like '%11%'
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. But now I have another problem.. I need to replace '11' with %s because I made this query dynamically. When I write instead '%11%' , '%' || %s || '%', I receive an error because yeah... list index out of range.  I don't know how to solve this. I need %s to replace it with the appropriate value, but I also need %, which leads to an even conflict.

Comment: You want to build your query in a function ?

Comment: Something like that. It is more code.. But yeah.. Something like: ".... from... where.. %s = ..., %s = ..., array_to_string(x, ';') like '%' || %s || '%' .format(12, 2, 3)

Comment: if you build it in a function you `have to use `execute` statement. You create you string with `$$` and then `execute my_string`